# Integrating React Native into exsting app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

[Integration with existing apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) shows

```
RCTRootView *rootView =
  [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL: jsCodeLocation
                              moduleName: @"RNHighScores"
                       initialProperties: nil
                           launchOptions: nil];
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view = rootView;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

that is you construct the RN view from the presenting view controller, not in the presented view controller.

Whereas for android, doc shows a way to create the ReactRootView from the presented(created) activity.

```
public class MyReactActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", null);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }

}
```

Would it be possible for iOS app to do something similar what the above android code do?  That is create a custom view controller and instantiate RCTRootView in viewDidLoad.
Is there any drawback doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does work. Although I don't know if there's any drawback.